# Dynamically change API route for SPA

Tags: vue.js, webpack, .net-core

I am currently building a SPA app using Vue.js and webpack to do our bundling. The backend API is built with .Net Core. When running locally, the Vue app is hitting localhost on the backend. I need to be able to change the route of the API dynamically based on the environment. Is there a way to do this without having to do a big switch statement that considers the current url? A requirement is that we are not allowed to change the webpack bundle for different environments, in other words, once it is bundled, it has to stay bundled. I have tried to pass static config files through to the bundle and dynamically change them based on the environment, but unfortunately that does not work, as it hits the values that were originally in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpack dev server has a proxy capability. You could use this to proxy to your locally running backend when developing.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

e.g. you can point anything from '/api' to 'localhost:8888/api' with the config.

Is your app the backend running on the same url when deployed? If not, you'll likely need a reverse proxy to pass along the requests to the backend.

You can use an axios interceptor so you only have that switch in one place:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    // check location.host name and append the backend url you want
  });
```

see https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

However, this is a little dangerous as the URLs in your switch statement will be strings, and therefore all of your environment URLs can be pulled out of your code even if minified/concatenated.

Another option is to add some sort of endpoint to the server your client side code is hosted, and when you start your app, query for that configuration.

Comment: No, the frontend and backend are running on different urls.

Comment: The question is how do I dynamically changed between localhost and the production api routes without rebundling. This answer does not work for dynamically flipping them.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you mean. I don't know of a way to achieve this without checking the URL you're currently on.  You could add a http interceptor to axios, and at least you'd only have one place where the switch statement is. I'll add some example code for that in my answer.